# Convert date string to Postgres timestamp timezones format

Tags: javascript, postgresql, momentjs, postgresql-9.6

I have the following date:

```
25-JAN-18 01.31.02 AM +00:00
```

and am trying to convert into a Postgres compatible `timestamp with time zone` format.

I am trying the following code to convert into the compatible format:

```
document.getElementById("parsedDate3").innerHTML = moment("25-JAN-18 01.31.02.923526 AM +00:00 ", "d-MMM-YY hh.mm.ss A Z");
```

But I am getting the output as

```
Mon Jan 01 2018 02:31:02 GMT+0100
```

Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

You are using lower-case `d` which is for the day of the week, 0 (Sunday) through 6 (Saturday).

Use upper-case `D` instead, which is for the day of the month.

Note that Moment's formatting tokens are slightly different than in other libraries and languages, so check the chart in the docs carefully.

Also:

- In your code you have 6 extra digits following the seconds.  If you need to account for those, use `SSSSSS`.  Otherwise they are ignored.
- You shouldn't assign a Moment object directly to an HTML element's `innerHTML` property.  Instead, call the `.format()` function on the Moment object first to generate a string.  You can optionally pass an argument to this function, to control the output format.

Comment: Is this how it should be `moment("25-JAN-18 01.31.02.923526 AM +00:00 ", "D-MMM-YY hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS A Z")` ?

Comment: Yes, tat should work, though you have an extra space at the end of your input string.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT to_timestamp('25-JAN-18 01.31.02.923526 AM +00:00', 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.US AM TZH:TZM');

         to_timestamp      
-------------------------------
 2018-01-25 02:31:02.923526+01
(1 row)
```

This will work for PostgreSQL v11 or better.

Earlier versions of `to_timestamp` cannot parse the time zone information yet.

If you need it to work on 9.6, and you know that the time zone is always going to be `+00:00`, you could simple omit the `TZH:TZM` in the format string.

Comment: Actually m doing insert and getting "error: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "25-JAN-18 01.31.02.923525 AM +00:00"

Comment: Well, each of your examples has a different format. How do the strings *really* look like? For microseconds, use the `US` format string.

Comment: Oh, I just saw it. It was a typo in the original question. I have updated it.

Comment: I am running following command `insert into test_date (INS_DATE) values (to_timestamp('25-JAN-18 01.31.02.923526 AM +00:00', 'DD-MON-YY HH.MI.SS.US AM TZH:TZM'));` and getting error `SQL Error: ERROR: "TZ"/"tz"/"OF" format patterns are not supported in to_date`

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL is this?

Comment: its PostgreSQL 9.6.11 on Google Cloud

Comment: I have added some more, maybe that is a workaround for you.